# Monetization Strip Account key Error in WSO2 APIM V4.1.0

Tags: stripe-payments, wso2-api-manager

I tried to use the stripe connected ID to APIM monetization. It is shows like this. How can I resolve this?

```
[2022-12-13 09:07:53,293] ERROR - ApisApiServiceImpl Error while changing monetization status for API ID : 44561b93-cd44-4959-877e-ddf2ff3170a9
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.MonetizationException: Stripe key of the connected account is empty.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the account id of the connected account which starts as `acct_***` while monetizing the API at image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/savdQ.png). The above account Id can be found under connect section of the Stripes platform or parent account.

[image: Image of monetization tab Publisher page]

Comment: I gave the connect account Id that place and save that configuration. After that I get the issue like this

Comment: You have to provide the connected account id every time you enable/disable monetization, please try again for a new API to re verify whether the issue is common in the environment,

Comment: I again provide that connect ID in that place. Please see the attached image below as the answer. It shows like this error while saving

Comment: Have you made any change to the name property of the following config by any chance.  The value for the connected account id is obtained from the above config. It has to be same as this "ConnectedAccountKey"" with same cases.

[[apim.monetization.additional_attributes]]
name = "ConnectedAccountKey"

Comment: No I added same as the APIM documents shown. Attached in the previous answer

Comment: The name property should have a capital "C", name = "ConnectedAccountKey".  The sample config you have shared only contains simple c and there is a case difference in the above name property which can cause this issue.